# How large a subset of $\mathbb{F}_q^d$ can determine all determinants?

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, determinants

Denote by $\mathbb{F}_q$ a finite field with $q$ elements. For $\mathcal{P}$ be arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{F}_q^d.$ We define the set

$$S:= \left\{ \det([x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d]): x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d \in \mathcal{P}\right\},$$

where $[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d]$ is $d \times d$ matrix with $d$ column vectors $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d.$

> What is the largest cardinality of  $\mathcal{P}$ such that $S \neq \mathbb{F}_q$?

(equivalently, What is the minimum value of $|\mathcal{P}|$ to make sure that $S=\mathbb{F}_q?$)

Comment: If we consider a subset $\mathcal{Q}$ of $M_d(\mathbb{F}_q)$ and 
$$S:=\left\{\det(A): A \in \mathcal{Q}\right\}.$$
Then, the minimum of cardinality of $\mathcal{Q}$ such that $S=\mathbb{F}_q$ for sure is 
$$N = q^{d^2} - \dfrac{|\mathrm{GL}_d(\mathbb{F}_q)|}{q-1} + 1.$$

How about the previous question?

Comment: I mean a different question that relative to main question.

Comment: More detail, the relation is that if we consider $\mathcal{P}^d := \left\{ [x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d]: x_i \in \mathcal{P}\right\} \subset M_d(\mathbb{F}_q).$

Comment: Oh, in my comment. It is only of $\mathcal{P}^d.$

Comment: I don't understand the Comment part of the post. N should be q, no larger and no smaller.  Gerhard "What Are You Really Counting?" Paseman, 2019.11.26.

Comment: Also, presumably you mean "how *small* a subset" rather than "how *large* a subset" (that being $q^d$ for subsets of $\mathbb F_q^d$)?

Comment: It is easy to get away with $\lvert\mathbb F_q/{\pm}\rvert + (d - 1)$ (assuming $d > 1$), by taking $x_{1r} = r e_1$ for $r \in \mathbb F_q/{\pm}$ and $x_i = e_i$ for $i > 1$.  Certainly $\mathcal P$ must have at least $\max \{d, \lvert\mathbb F_q/\pm\rvert\}$ elements.

Comment: Also, when q is 2, the answer is d+1, using a zero vector and involving rows of an identity matrix. Likely one can extend this to larger q to get an upper bound of d + q*log q or some other slow growing function of q.  Is the determinant being evaluated over the field, or over the integers? Gerhard "Where You Do Arithmetic Matters" Paseman, 2019.11.26.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman, since the determinant can't be computed over the integers if $q$ isn't prime, it had better be done over $\mathbb F_q$.  (Also, your [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346972/how-large-a-subset-of-mathbbf-qd-can-determine-all-determinants#comment868717_346972) is the special case of [mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346972/how-large-a-subset-of-mathbbf-qd-can-determine-all-determinants#comment868716_346972) when $q = 2$; and it is clear that $d + q$ elements is enough, but not (to me) whether that's asymptotically optimal.)

Comment: Actually, using @Lspices idea, you may be able to use fewer than q+d elements, especially when you can factor most of the numbers. Here it is even more important where the arithmetic occurs.  Gerhard "Use Square Root Of Q?" Paseman, 2019.11.26.

Comment: @Lspice, I think it can, but it matters how the results are interpreted. I don't mind letting 1 live in many different rings. Gerhard "What Does The Customer Want?" Paseman, 2019.11.26.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman, 1 can live in many different rings, but (for example) $\sqrt{-1} \in \mathbb F_9$ cannot live in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101519/discussion-between-gerhard-paseman-and-lspice).

Comment: I am very sorry about my english. I edited to make sure all of you can understand the question.

Comment: You probably mean "the minimal cardinality of $\mathcal{Q}$ such that $S=\mathbb{F}_q$ for sure is $N = q^{d^2} - \dfrac{|\mathrm{GL}_d(\mathbb{F}_q)|}{q-1} + 1$" Or, equivalently, "the maximal cardinality of $\mathcal{Q}$ such that $|S|<q$ is possible is $N = q^{d^2} - \dfrac{|\mathrm{GL}_d(\mathbb{F}_q)|}{q-1}$".

Comment: do you know the answer for $d=2$?

Comment: One trivial lower bound is $q^{n−1},$ given by all vectors in a maximal proper subspace (for example, all vectors whose first entry equals 0).

Answer (score 1):

This answer gives an upper bound of size

$$\frac{ q^{d-2}(q^d-1)}{(q^{d-1}-1)}+ \frac{ (q^d-1) q^{\frac{d-1}{2}} (q-1)^{\frac{5}{2}} } { 2 (q^{d-1}-1)  \sqrt{ q^d-1- q(q-1)^3} } + 1 =  q^{d-1} +\frac{ q^3}{2} + o(q^3) $$

Because Nguyễn Văn Thế gave a lower bound of $q^{d-1}$ in the comments, it is close to sharp for large $d$. The gap can be improved by a factor of $\frac{q^{1/2}}{2}$ by just doing more calculations at the end.

**Lemma 1**: If $|\mathcal P| > q^{d-1}$ and $| \wedge^{d-1}(\mathcal P^{d-1} )|\geq q (q-1)^2 $ then $| \wedge^d (\mathcal P^{d})| = q$.

*Proof*: Let $\mathcal Q=  \wedge^{d-1}(\mathcal P^{d-1} )$, viewed as a subset of $\mathbb F_q^d$. Since $\wedge^d (\mathcal P^d)$ is the image of $\mathcal P\times \mathcal Q$ under the dot product, it suffices to show that for all $\alpha \in \mathbb F_q$, $\alpha = a \cdot b$ for some $a \in \mathcal P, b \in \mathcal Q$. To do this, we use Fourier analysis

$$\left| \left\{ a\in \mathcal P, b \in \mathcal Q | a \cdot b = \alpha \right\}\right| = \sum_{ \psi: \mathbb F_q \to \mathbb C^\times}\frac{ \overline{\psi(\alpha)} }{ q}  \sum_{a \in \mathcal P} \sum_{b \in \mathcal Q} \psi(ab) $$

The term for $\psi=1 $ has size $\frac{ |\mathcal P| |\mathcal Q|}{q}$. Assuming for contradiction that the sum vanishes, the remaining $q-1$ terms must cancel this one, so one must have size at least $$\frac{ |\mathcal P| |\mathcal Q|}{(q-1) q}$$ which implies

$$ \frac{ |\mathcal P| |\mathcal Q|}{q-1}\geq \left| \sum_{a \in \mathcal P} \sum_{b \in \mathcal Q} \psi(ab) \right| = \sqrt{ |\mathcal P|} \sqrt{ \sum_{a \in \mathbb F_q^d} \left| \sum_{b \in \mathcal Q} \psi(ab) \right|^2}=  \sqrt{ |\mathcal P | |\mathcal Q| q^d}$$ by Caucy-Schwarz and the Plancherel formula.

Squaring both sides and cancelling, we get $|\mathcal P | |\mathcal Q| \geq q^d (q-1)^2$, contradicting our assumptions. QED

**Lemma 2**: $| \wedge^{d-1}(\mathcal P^{d-1} )|$ is at least the number of codimension $1$ linear subspaces of $\mathbb F_q^d$ that contain at least $q^{d-2}$ nonzero elements of $\mathbb F_q^d$.

*Proof*: For each such linear subspace, not all its elements lie in a codimension $2$ linear subspace, or else there would be $q^{d-2}-1$ nonzero elements, so there must be $d-1$ linearly independent, whose $\wedge^{d-1}$ produces a nonzero vector perpendicular to that subspace. Because we never have a nonzero vector perpendicular to two subspaces, the vectors in $\wedge^{d-1} (\mathcal P)$ produced this way are distinct for distinct subspaces. QED

**Lemma 3**: If there are less than $q (q-1)^2$ codimension $1$ linear subspaces with at least $q^{d-2}$ nonzero elements of $\mathcal P$, then $|\mathcal P| \leq \frac{ q^{d-2}(q^d-1)}{(q^{d-1}-1)}+ \frac{ (q^d-1) q^{\frac{d-1}{2}} (q-1)^{\frac{5}{2}} } { 2 (q^{d-1}-1)  \sqrt{ q^d-1- q(q-1)^3} } + 1 $.

*Proof*: Let $\mathcal P'= \mathcal P \setminus \{0\}$. Consider a random variable $X$ where we pick a random codimension $1$ linear subspace $H$ and count its intersection with $\mathcal P'$. We have $ \mathbb E[X] = \frac{ |\mathcal P'| (q^{d-1}-1)}{(q^d-1)}$ and $$\mathbb E[X^2] = \sum_{x, y \in \mathcal P'} \mathbb P( x, y \in H) =  \frac{ |\mathcal P'|^2 (q^{d-2}-1)}{q^{d}- 1} + \sum_{x, y \in \mathcal P'}\left( \mathbb P( x, y \in H)- \frac{ q^{d-2}-1}{q^d-1} \right) $$

$$ =\frac{ |\mathcal P'|^2 (q^{d-2}-1)}{q^{d}-1} + \sum_{ \substack{ x, y\in \mathcal P'\\ y = cx } } \left( \frac{ q^{d-1}-1}{q^d-1}  - \frac{q^{d-2}-1}{q^{d}-1}  \right) $$ $$ \leq  \frac{ |\mathcal P'|^2 (q^{d-2}-1)}{q^{d}-1}  + \frac{ |\mathcal P'| (q-1) (q^{d-1} -q^{d-2} )} { q^d-1}$$

so $$\operatorname{Var}(X) \leq   \frac{ |\mathcal P'| (q-1) (q^{d-1} -q^{d-2} )} { q^d-1}- \frac{ |\mathcal P'|^2 ( (q^{d-1}-1)^2 - (q^{d-2}-1)(q^d-1)) }{(q^{d}-1)^2}   = \frac{ |\mathcal P'| (q-1) (q^{d-1} -q^{d-2} )} { q^d-1}- \frac{ |\mathcal P'|^2 (q-1) (q^{d-1} - q^{d-2} ) }{ (q^d-1)^2} $$

$$ \leq \frac{ (q-1) (q^{d-1} - q^{d-2} )}{ 4} $$

And thus, by Cantelli's inequality, the probability that $X$ is at least $q^{d-2}$ is at least $ \frac{ ( \mathbb E[X] - q^{d-2} )^2 }{ ( \mathbb E[X] - q^{d-2} )^2+ \operatorname{Var}(X) }$. Because the number of such linear subspaces is at most $q (q-1)^2$, this probability is at most $\frac{ q(q-1)^3}{(q^d-1)}$, and so 
$$\frac{ ( \mathbb E[X] - q^{d-2} )^2 }{ ( \mathbb E[X] - q^{d-2} )^2+ \operatorname{Var}(X) } \leq \frac{ q(q-1)^3}{(q^d-1)}$$
that is
$$ ( \mathbb E[X] - q^{d-2} )^2 \leq \frac{ q(q-1)^3}{(q^d-1)- q(q-1)^3} \operatorname{Var}(X) \leq  \frac{ q^{d-1} (q-1)^5}{4( (q^d-1)- q(q-1)^3) } $$

which gives

$$\mathbb E[X] \leq q^{d-2} +  \frac{ q^{\frac{d-1}{2}} (q-1)^{\frac{5}{2}} } { 2 \sqrt{ q^d-1- q(q-1)^3} }$$

$$ |\mathcal P'| \leq \frac{ q^{d-2}(q^d-1)}{(q^{d-1}-1)}+ \frac{ (q^d-1) q^{\frac{d-1}{2}} (q-1)^{\frac{5}{2}} } { 2 (q^{d-1}-1)  \sqrt{ q^d-1- q(q-1)^3} }$$

$$|\mathcal P| \leq\frac{ q^{d-2}(q^d-1)}{(q^{d-1}-1)}+ \frac{ (q^d-1) q^{\frac{d-1}{2}} (q-1)^{\frac{5}{2}} } { 2 (q^{d-1}-1)  \sqrt{ q^d-1- q(q-1)^3} } + 1$$

QED

Comment: @NguyễnVănThế The number of codimension one linear subspaces is $(q^d-1)/(q-1)$. Because at most $q (q-1)^2$ have that property, to get the probability that a random one has that property, we divide.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a conversation with Lspice, here is an idea to play with to (for large q) get away with much fewer than q+d vectors. I will show a non optimal example.

Let d be at least 4, and q sufficiently large (bigger than 1000). I pick q=1009. The first row will have ten powers of two, from 1 to 512. The second will have seven powers of three, from 1 to 729. The third row will have powers of five from 1 to 625. (Each of these are really the power times the ith basis vector). The last row will have the remaining primes, and where needed, products of smaller primes. This will be 165 primes, about a similar number of products of two primes, and a smattering (less than four hundred all told) of products of three primes, not necessarily distinct. This gives less than 500 vectors to give positive determinants up to 1008.

Of course one needs d distinct vectors to give a nonzero determinant, but not much more to get all values of the field as determinants. And this is computing determinants as if they were integer matrices. Further savings can be realized if one does the determinant computation over the field itself.

I do not have a good sense of asymptotic or even a good lower bound for this. I imagine one needs a quantity like k(q^(1/k)) involved, but I can't show that is a lower bound.

Gerhard "Has Got This Party Started" Paseman, 2019.11.26.

Comment: I was rather loose in my estimations above. There are less than one hundred twenty products of two primes involved, and less than ten of three primes, so less than three hundred fifty vectors needed.  With d=5 we can involve powers of seven and get away with a smaller number of vectors. Gerhard "This Is Just The Beginning" Paseman, 2019.11.26.

Comment: One thing that I can't figure out how to make use of is that we get sign changes for free, by swapping rows, so we don't really have to cover (in the $q$ prime case) $0, \dotsc, q - 1$ but only, say, $0, \dotsc, \tfrac1 2(q - 1)$.

Comment: We don't . I am trying for not quite logarithmic representation. In the case of q=1009, I only need plus minus 504, which saves on about 70 primes and a few products.  In the asymptotic picture, a multiplicative factor of two is easily ignored, since the work is in dividing up the factors.  Gerhard "Is Having More Fun Dividing" Paseman, 2019.11.26.